# scrape specific table element with scrapy

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape the content from a website within a specific `<td>` tag. The tutorial shows me how to download all of the data -- I just want the data from one `<td>`. halp!

example generic table code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>1,1</td>
<td>1,2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2,1</td>
<td>2,2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I don't know how to get just the `2,2` value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `response.xpath()` or `response.css()` shortcuts to get the last `td` element in a `table`. Examples:

```
response.xpath("//table//td[last()]/text()").extract_first()
response.xpath("//table//td/text()").extract()[-1]
response.css("table td::text").extract()[-1]
```

Comment: And if I'm looking for an arbitrarily positioned <td>, say, #223 of 900, how do I select that one?

Comment: @hiddenhobbit sure, sample: `response.xpath("//table//td[223]/text()").extract_first()` - indexing starts with 1 inside xpath expressions.

Comment: @alecxe how would you do that same reference using a css selector?  I am trying to do a similar task using css selectors and I keep getting `listindex out of range` error...  `case_number = tr.css('td').extract()[-1]` and the same applies whether the index is -1, 0, 1, 4, whatever